# Page speed Insights: Render blocking font-awesome

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome, cdn, pagespeed

I am using font-awesome 5.3.1 css and adding to my page like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var shared = {};
        shared.css = ["https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css"];
        (function () {
            var container = document.querySelector('head');
            shared.css.forEach(function (href) {
                var css = document.createElement('link');
                css.href = href;
                css.rel = 'stylesheet';
                css.type = 'text/css';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
            });
        })(); 
    </script>
```

This is at the very end of the body yet when I run my page on PageSpeed it complains of the render blocking css related to font awesome.

How do I fix this? I tried font awesome cdn but it only support 4.7 and there is no new version on it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif he is trying to load CSS in a defered way to increase PageSpeed points...

Comment: Well in HTML 4 it is incorrect to put the css in the body end. I would end up having to put in head section which is render blocking. So I am using JS to load css only after page has been parsed at the very end of the body tag.

Comment: MarcoDalZovo is right.

Comment: it will decrease his pagespeed because he added a JS and he will keep loading the CSS ... so simply load the CSS without JS

Comment: @Mrug are you executing that javascript code AFTER the page loads completely?

Comment: @MarcoDalZovo: As noted previously it's at the end of body </body> tag.

Comment: @Mrug ok, it's at the end of body, but if you execute that javascript when the page is loading, you won't resolve the problem. You need to execute it ONLY when the page has fully loaded. You can refer to body onload method...
Or you can put above-the-line CSS inline (so <style> tag on the page) to resolve that...

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this Javascript after the page loads completely. See follow:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' (){
    /*** Put the code here **/

})
```

This will ensure that script is loaded once the Document is loaded fully.